# if statement with list contains

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a list which contains the numbers (lijstkleur) 1,4,6,7.
I also have a range from 0 till 8.
Now i have te following code:

```
for x in range(0, len(L), 1):
    if x in lijstkleur == True:
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text=string[x], fg="yellow", bg="red")
        self.label.pack(side=LEFT)
    else:
        self.label = Label(self.frame, text=string[x], fg="white", bg="red")
        self.label.pack(side=LEFT)
```

but all the numbers become white, what is wrong with this if statement

Answer (score 5):

No need to use `== True`:

```
if x in lijstkleur:
```

The expression `x in lijstkleur==True` is interpreted as `(x in lijstkleur) and (lijstkleur == True)`; a list is never equal to boolean `True` and thus you end up testing `something and False`, guaranteed to be `False` instead. This is called [comparison chaining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), making expressions like `10 < a < 20` possible.

You can simplify your `range()` call to just `len(L)`:

```
for x in range(len(L)):
```

and there is no need to repeat the `.pack()` call:

```
if x in lijstkleur:
    self.label=Label(self.frame,text=string[x],fg="yellow",bg="red")
else:
    self.label=Label(self.frame,text=string[x],fg="white",bg="red")
self.label.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Comment: And no need for `for x in range(0,len(L),1)` when `for x in range(len(L))` will do. Or `for x, s in zip(L, string)`. And `self.label.pack(side=LEFT)` can be hoisted ... There's a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional isn't evaluating the way you think it is. It's doing this:

```
if (x in lijstkleur) and (lijstkleur==True):
```

The result of `lijstkleur==True` is always `False`, since a list is never equal to a boolean, so the conditional always returns `False`. What you want is this:

```
if x in lijstkleur:
```

Comment: `lijstkleur==True` is `True`.. or `False`.. neither of them are iterable. Why don't you get any error message?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Whoops; skipped a piece. Fixed.

Comment: Ahh.. I forgot that operators can be on both side. Thx!